# Running into an issue trying to use certbot to create an SSL cert for my server

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

While I have done this before, I do not recall running into this issue, so I don't understand what step I am missing.

I am trying to create an SSL cert for my server using certbot however, where I am getting a failure is with the acme_challenge. Im getting an "Unauthorized" failure. The thing is, I can't figure out how to get the challenge to set in the DNS. When certbot runs, I had recalled that it would pause and give you the challenge to set in DNS, but that is not happening.

It is throwing the error to the terminal window showing the challenge and saying it's failing. The output is below.

```
root@systopian-web2:~# sudo certbot certonly --agree-tos --email admin@mydomain.tld --webroot -w /var/lib/letsencrypt/ -d mydomain.tld -d www.mydomain.tld
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator webroot, Installer None
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for mydomain.tld
http-01 challenge for www.mydomain.tld
Using the webroot path /var/lib/letsencrypt for all unmatched domains.
Waiting for verification...
Challenge failed for domain systopian.web2.tldm
Challenge failed for domain www.systopian-web2.tld
http-01 challenge for mydomain.tld
http-01 challenge for www.mydomain.tld
Cleaning up challenges
Some challenges have failed.

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: mydomain.tld
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   mydomain.tld/.well-known/acme-challenge/xylqef3u7PthzjE7f1cGIhdGwAMls0wWzvODkQwb_f4
   [119.28.132.32]: "<html>\r\n<head><title>404 Not
   Found</title></head>\r\n<body bgcolor=\"white\">\r\n<center><h1>404
   Not Found</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>"

   Domain: www.mydomain.tld
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
/www.mydomain.tld/auth/login [45.77.154.240]: "<html
   lang=\"\">\n    <head>\n    \n    <meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n
   <meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=edge\">\n    <!--
   Tel"

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
```